# Permutacion con chars en C++

Tags: c++, c, recursión, quicksort, puntero-a-función

Buenas soy yo otra vez con el mismo caso, he estado tratando de averiguar como funciona pero aun tengo muchas dudas. Segun lo compilado, lo que hace el codigo es imprimir todas las combinaciones posibles de una cadena de Chars, ejemplo :
cadena = "ABC";
Resultados = ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA;

Adjunto el Codigo

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int formas = 0;
void Cambiar(char *x, char *y)
{
   char pivote;
   pivote = *x;
   *x = *y;
   *y = pivote;
}

void permutar(char *Ar, int izq, int der)
{

int i;

if (izq == der)
{
    //* Si en caso todas las formas posibles ya
    //*esten en el arreglo Ar, entonces lo imprimimos
    if (formas < 10)
    {
        cout << "0" << formas << ".\t" << Ar << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << formas << ".\t" << Ar << endl;
    }

    formas++; //! Vamos aumentando el numero de permutaciones
}
else
{
    for (i = izq; i <= der; i++)
    {
        Cambiar((Ar + izq), (Ar + i));
        permutar(Ar, izq + 1, der);
        Cambiar((Ar + izq), (Ar + i));
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int n = 0;
char cadena[] = "AEBCD";

cout << "\n\n\t[ PERMUTACIONES - MESA - ABOGADOS ] \n\n";

n = strlen(cadena);

permutar(cadena, 0, n - 1);
cout << "\nSe realizo " << formas << " permutaciones.en total\n"<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

Les comento todo lo que pude comprender y lo que no hasta el momento :

LO QUE PUDE COMPRENDER :

1. en la funcion main se crea n para guardar el tamanio de la cadena, se le manda a la funcion permutar 3 parametros,el primero es la cadena, el segundo la posicion inicial, y el ultimo la posicion final(aunque no muy seguro el porque el -1)
2. En la funcion permutar crea el i para que sea iterador, el if principal se pregunta si Izq es igual a dere, si es asi, entra e imprime la cadena. pero sino, pues alli empiezan mis dudas...

LO QUE NO PUDE COMPRENDER :

1. La funcion Cadena recibe dos argumentos de tipo char, pero no entiendo el porque en la funcion permutar envian la cadena pero tambien le suma la posicion izq e i.. Esto no lo tengo tan claro ya que segun tengo entendido no se puede sumar chars con ints..
2. Despues de la primera aplicacion de la funcion cambiar, aplica recursividad para volverse a llamar asi misma, pero no entiendo porque abajo le pone otra vez a la funcion cambiar.. no se supone que una vez que entre a permutar ya abandone el resto y empieze nuevamente? seria de mas poner nuevamente a cambiar ya que no se aplicaria..o si? tengo muchos problemas conrecursividad jaja..
3. En la funcion cambiar recibe como parametro dos cadenas (punteros) .. no entiendo porque puede poner a pivote la cadena x.. no se supone que no se puede poner un char* a un char ?

Agradeceria mucho de su ayuda, no es un examen o algo asi, pero busco aprender mucho de recursividad ya que aun soy muy novato en ese ambito, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> La funcion Cadena recibe dos argumentos de tipo char, pero no entiendo el porque en la funcion permutar envian la cadena pero tambien le suma la posicion izq e i.. Esto no lo tengo tan claro ya que segun tengo entendido no se puede sumar chars con ints..

No estás enviando ninguna cadena. La función `Cadena` recibe **dos punteros**. Un puntero no es una cadena, es una variable que almacena posiciones de memoria.

Así pues, lo que sucede en `permutar` es que se calcula la posición de los dos elementos a intercambiar. `Ar` apunta al inicio de la cadena y `izq` e `i` son dos enteros que se usan como *offset*.

Por ejemplo, si en la cadena `"ABCDEFG"` quisiésemos intercambiar las posiciones 3 y 5 haríamos lo siguiente:

```
Cambiar(Ar + 3, Ar + 5);
```

`Ar + 3` calcula la posición de memoria donde se encuentra el elemento numero 3 (el 4º en la lista), mientras que `Ar + 5` calcula la posición de memoria del elemento 5:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
A B C D E F G
^     ^   ^
Ar    |   Ar + 5
      Ar + 3
```

> Despues de la primera aplicacion de la funcion cambiar, aplica recursividad para volverse a llamar asi misma, pero no entiendo porque abajo le pone otra vez a la funcion cambiar.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer para entender los algoritmos es coger papel y lapiz y escribir tu mismo todo lo que va sucediendo

> En la funcion cambiar recibe como parametro dos cadenas (punteros) .. no entiendo porque puede poner a pivote la cadena x.. no se supone que no se puede poner un char* a un char ?

Si te fijas, en la función `Cambiar` se hace uso del operador `*`. Este operador recupera el valor al que apunta el puntero. Es decir, `pivote` no está almacenando la posición de memoria apuntada por `x` sino el valor que se encuentra en esa posición de memoria:

```
  char * cadena = "ABCDEFG";

  char c = *cadena; // c = 'A'

  char c = cadena; // No tiene sentido char=char* ¿¿??
```

Comment: Agradecido por la respuesta hermano